# Magento 2 - Custom 404 page for disabled products

Tags: magento2.3.1, 404-page

In Magento 2 I am looking to create a module that adds a custom 404 page specifically for disabled products from Magento Admin.

Can anyone help me how I can proceed to get the desired output?

Comment: reference=> https://github.com/fransyrcc/disabled-products-redirect

Comment: keep in mind that the extension hasn't been maintained in 2 years

Answer (score 0):

create a plugin to check the product status ***"afterGetStatus"*** method for ***class \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product***,

if the product status is disabled, then create a custom 404 page and forward the controller to that. Find below the code to do that, I have checked it and it is working.

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
<plugin name="change_product" type="Rahul\Disabledproductredirect\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="1" />
```

**Plugin/Product.php**

```
namespace Rahul\Disabledproductredirect\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;


    class Product
    {

        private $forward;
        private $request;


        public function __construct(Forward $forward,Http $request)
        {

            $this->forward = $forward;
            $this->request  = $request;
        }

        public function afterGetStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
        {
            //return $result;
            if($result == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED && $this->request->getControllerName()=='product' && $this->request->getActionName() == 'view')
            {

               $this->forward->forward('noroute');

            }

            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to add your custom 404 page identifier instead of "noroute"

Answer (score 0):

**One way to perform such redirect is adding a plugin for \Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index. Configuration for etc/di.xml for this purpose:**

```
 <type name="Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index">
        <plugin name="noroute_redirect" 
                type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\Noroute" />
    </type>
```

**And the plugin will look like:**

```
namespace YourModule\YourVendor\Plugin;

class Noroute
{
    private $redirectFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory)
    {
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Cms\Controller\Noroute\Index $index,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        return $this->redirectFactory->create()
                    ->setPath('404notfound');
    }
}
```

**You should also create a CMS Page specifying the 404notfound url-key to handle request to this url.
Unfortunately, Magento 2 framework does not allow to save pages with number-only url key.** for [more](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/404-page-url-in-magento-2/td-p/56504)

Hope this help you,